# Упорядочение памяти (memory ordering) в QAtomicInteger

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имеется класс очереди запросов `RequestQueue`:

```
QQueue<Request> _requests;
QAtomicInt      _locker;

void RequestQueue::enqueue(const Request &request) {
    while(_locker.testAndSetOrdered(0,1) == false)
        QThread::yieldCurrentThread();

    _requests.enqueue(request);
    _locker = 0;
}

Request RequestQueue::dequeue() {
    forever {
        if(_locker.testAndSetOrdered(0,1) == true) {
            if(_requests.isEmpty() == true) {
                _locker = 0; break;
            }

            const Request request
                = _requests.dequeue();

            _locker = 0;

            return request;
        }

        QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
    }

    return Request();
}
```

Решил попробовать реализацию без мьютексов, поскольку имеется множество конкурирующих между собой потоков, как на запись в очередь, так и на чтение из оной, и хотелось получить максимально возможное ускорение.

Код работает корректно, однако смущает наличие непонимания того, какой следует использовать метод для `test-and-set`. В приведённом примере - это `QAtomicInteger::testAndSetOrdered()`, но почему бы вместо него не использовать, скажем, `QAtomicInteger::testAndSetRelaxed()` или ещё один из двух других оставшихся вариантов.

[Справка](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qatomicinteger.html) не сильно многословна по этому поводу (впрочем, допускаю, что просто перевожу неверно):

> QAtomicInteger provides several implementations of the atomic
>   test-and-set, fetch-and-store, and fetch-and-add functions. Each
>   implementation defines a memory ordering semantic that describes how
>   memory accesses surrounding the atomic instruction are executed by the
>   processor. Since many modern architectures allow out-of-order
>   execution and memory ordering, using the correct semantic is necessary
>   to ensure that your application functions properly on all processors.

Какой же из вариантов *memory ordering* может быть предпочтителен к выбору конкретно в ситуации с примером из моего вопроса?

Comment: Это сложная тема, по которой можно много написать. Если кратко: используйте `testAndSetOrdered`, пока чётко не будете понимать, что и как работает. Или вообще забудьте про такие низкоуровневые оптимизации. Я писал об этом(не Qt, но суть одна) статьи: [раз](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/05/16/memory_barriers.aspx), [два](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/08/14/parallel-world-p4.aspx) и [три](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/10/15/parallel_world_p5.aspx). Чтение всех трёх поможет немного прояснить вопрос, я надеюсь

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо, обязательно почитаю.

Comment: @ixSci, м-да, тема как минимум на весьма длительное изучение, но того стоит. Ответ на мой вопрос в Ваших статьях имеется. Но не могли бы Вы уточнить один момент? Получается, вот эта реализация с ordered-блокировкой у меня в примере, она ведь по сути ничем не лучше использования обычного мьютекса, правильно?

Comment: По корректности ничего сказать не могу, но по сути, это обычный spin-lock, который является частью любого уважающего себя мьютекса, перед переходом в режим ядра. Я бы попробовал разные мьютексы(стандартный, бустовый, Qtый), если есть проблемы с производительностью и выбрал бы лучший. Возможно Вам подошёл бы shared mutex, когда много читателей могут одновременно входить в критическую секцию.